# Grails 3 + Springboot dependencies

Tags: grails, spring-boot

I have a Grails 3 application that depends on dependencies that are managed by springboot. How to bootstrap those springboot dependend dependencies from Grails so i can use the services and beans from the dependensies.

Extending the Application.groovy packageNames funktion by the packages used in the dependencies seem to bootstrap most of it but not all....

Comment: `packageNames()` is only about domain classes

Comment: how to bootstrap the springboot manually?

Comment: what are trying to do in general?

Comment: Initializing Bringboot dependencies from a Springboot application is easy. I simply added the package of the dependencies to the  @ComponentScan annotation in my Master Applciation

Comment: But how to do that from Grails so graisl will find the other @Configuration annotations and through that initialize the rest

Comment: The projects the grails application depends on provides a lot of services i would like to use. The grails App is simply to provide a user interface to control those services. The services initialize db stuff and remote connections. I don't want to reimplement all of this. I simply want to use the beas provide .

Comment: you can add your appContext.xml to grails config

Comment: i have no appcontext.xml i used only spring annotations

Comment: what dependencies are not initialized?

Comment: every springboot project i wrote. I need the equivalent for @Configuration()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"some.package"}) to use in grails to extend the componentscan to my components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency that manages the MongoDB Connection is working fine if started standalone, but is not generating the MongoRepositories if used inside a grails application. It seems grails enables jpareporitories, but not MongoReporitories. I simply hat do add @EnableMongoRepositories to my MongoDB configuration and now both types of repositories are generated.

Summed up I had to use

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
  @Override
  boolean limitScanningToApplication() {
    false
  }
}
```

to enable scanning as mentioned above and

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
```

to enable MongoRepositoryGeneration inside of a grails app

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
  @Override
  boolean limitScanningToApplication() {
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostly nice. Now only the JPA part is missing. The repository Classes are not getting generated.